# How do I deal with three or more values being stored in stack pointer for MIPS Assembly?

Tags: assembly, return, mips, cpu-registers, mars-simulator

This program is meant to allow the user to put dashes ('-' and '|') to form boxes, connecting vertices of a 3x3 grid.

So call this a beginner Assembly programmer question if you will, but I am having issues with storing three or more values on the stack pointer. I would like to return to main from loop1 by popping the return address off of the stack pointer; however, in checkMove the stack pointer is added to twice.

How can I solve my issue so that I can return to main from loop1?

```
    .data #Data declaration segment
board: .ascii   "\n\n   . . .          . 0 . 1 ."
       .ascii     "\n                  2   3   4"
       .ascii     "\n   . . .          . 5 . 6 ."
       .ascii     "\n                  7   8   9"
       .asciiz    "\n   . . .          . a . b .\n"
offset: .byte     6,   8,  33,  35,  37,  62,  64,  89,  91,  93,  118, 120
marker: .byte    '-', '-', '|', '|', '|', '-', '-', '|', '|', '|', '-', '-'

    .text #Text declaration statement

main:
    li $t0, 6 #Number of loops/moves to make
    jal loop1
    
    #Print game board
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, board
    syscall
    
    #Exit Program
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
    
loop1:
    #Load return address onto stack pointer
    subu $sp, $sp, 4 
    sw $ra, ($sp) #Store $ra into $sp
    
    #Read integer for marking excluding a and b
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    
    move $a0, $v0 #Set $v0 to $a0
    jal markMove #Jump to markMove; return address is set in $ra
    sub $t0, $t0, 1 #Decrement counter by 1
    bnez $t0, loop1 #Return to L1 if counter not 0
    
    #Once counter is 0, pop return address off stack pointer
    lw $ra, ($sp)
    addu $sp, $sp, 4
    
    jr $ra
    
#Mark a move on the game board
#Input : $a0 (Integer move 0-9)
markMove:
    ##Prepare to pass necessary variables ($v0, $ra) into function.
    
    #Push return address ($ra) onto stack pointer
    subu $sp, $sp, 4 
    sw $ra, ($sp) #Store $ra into $sp
    #Push $t0 onto stack pointer
    subu $sp, $sp, 4

    sw $t0, ($sp) #Store $t0 into $sp
    
    lb $t0, offset($a0)
    
    #Actually mark now
    lb $t1, marker($a0) #Find the marker
    sb $t1, board($t0) #Place the marker at spot in board

#Clear stack pointer ($sp) and return to $ra
loop2:
    ##Prepare to take the variables ($v0, $ra) from above.
    lw $t0, ($sp) #Pop $t0 off of stack pointer
    addu $sp, $sp, 4
    lw $ra, ($sp) #Pop $t0 off of stack pointer
    addu $sp, $sp, 4
    
    jr $ra #Return to return address; jump register
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are pushing `$ra` on each iteration that reads a number from user (6 loops/moves according to your commented code).

You should only store the return address once every time you enter a new function/procedure, and restore it prior to returning from it.

So you would add another label after you save context and use it in your control loop. In this example I used `inner_loop`:

```
...
loop1:
    #Load return address onto stack pointer
    subu $sp, $sp, 4 
    sw $ra, ($sp) #Store $ra into $sp
    
inner_loop:
    #Read integer for marking excluding a and b
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    
    move $a0, $v0 #Set $v0 to $a0
    jal markMove #Jump to markMove; return address is set in $ra
    sub $t0, $t0, 1 #Decrement counter by 1
    bnez $t0, inner_loop #Return to L1 if counter not 0
    
    #Once counter is 0, pop return address off stack pointer
...
```

Comment: Very nice answer! Thank you for the aid with that. One question: was my question not worded correctly? Can you theoretically keep storing these return addresses on the stack pointer? I thought I read that the stack pointer can only hold 2 values.

Comment: @IDoNotKnowHowToProgram: the stack **pointer** only holds one value (the address of the top of the stack). The stack itself is held on memory, and you can "stack" there various kind of information. For example you can store there returning addresses that is what you are doing in the prologue of each function. You can also store context, for example the value of a register to "free" it for other purposes and the restore it (you do it with `$t0` in `markMove`. So as long as you have free memory assigned to the stack area you can push there values.

Comment: In your program you were storing multiple times the same return address. That in itself is not a problem, but your logic did not restore properly those values afterwards (the stack was imbalanced), and I am sure you meant to only store it once when entering the function.

Comment: Great reply again. Thanks for the help @gusbro !